# How to bind a dataset that was created in the Data Access layer to a gridview in the UI?

Tags: asp.net

Below is the code..

```
namespace ConfigurationSystem.DataAccess
{
    public class DataAccessLayer
    {
        public DataSet GetRoleCreationDetails(int? Roles_Id, string Code, string Name, string IsActive)
        {

            try
            {
                string con = @"Data Source=PAVANKUMAR-PC\PAVAN;Initial Catalog=ConfigurationSystem;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "SP_GetRoleCreationDetails";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserRole_Id", Roles_Id);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", Code);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Name);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", IsActive);

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(dataset);
                //status = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@OuptputParam"].Value);
                return dataset;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that DataAccessLayer be a `static` class, it serves no purpose having an instance of this class

Answer (score 1):

You pass the dataset to the UI and do:

```
myGrid.DataSource = GetReturnedDS();
myGrid.DataBind();
```

In other words in the UI:

```
Dataset ds = MyBLL.GetData();
myGrid.DataSource = ds;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

In the BLL:

```
public static DataSet GetData()
 {
  return  DLL.GetData();
 }
```

And in DLL:

```
public static DataSet GetData()
 {
  //your code here
  return yourDataSet;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create object of your `class DataAccessLayer` first. Either use using at the top of form or prefix class name with namespace as given below. You need to use meaning full names for you class and namespace.

```
grid1.DataSource = new ConfigurationSystem.DataAccess.DataAccessLayer().GetRoleCreationDetails("1", "code", "name", "true");
grid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: A dataaccesslayer serves no purpose to have an instance of the class, I would make that entire class `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your aspx.cs

```
myGrid.DataSource = new DataAccessLayer().DataGetRoleCreationDetails(parameters here..)
myGrid.DataBind();
```